# Developer name constraints in App Store

Tags: android

I'm creating my developer account and I have to choose developer name now. I wonder if I can use any name that is availeable or should I use my own name and surname. The problem is that I dont have company with that name. Can google ban my account because I have same name as some other company(even if they created their developer account after me)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is pretty liberal about choosing developer names (unlike iOS App Store) and so you can choose any name you want. I'd recommend you to buy a domain name linked to that name (won't cost much). The only case I can think of is where a registered company (and a popular one) asks Google to take down your name, but I think it's a long shot in any case.

Comment: I found another developer with very similar name to the one that i want to choose(it is same but with Live at the end). Is it ok to make so similara name?